# How to Save data to mongodb database by JSON object?

Tags: node.js, json, mongodb, mongoose, postman

I want to save data into the database. I used to check my URL by using database. But i couldn't . 
It shows this message :

> DeprecationWarning: current URL string parser is deprecated, and will
>   be removed in a future version. To use the new parser, pass option {
>   useNewUrlParser: true } to MongoClient.connect. listning to port 3000
>   { _id: 5d9775340007cc3c8cb34caf } { _id: 5d9775340007cc3c8cb34caf,
>   __v: 0 } Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

**This is my router file code:**

```
router.post("/timeTableRegistration", function(req, res) {
  const newTimeTable = new classTimeTable({
    object: req.body
  });
  console.log(newTimeTable);
  newTimeTable
    .save()
    .then(result => {
      console.log(result);
      res.json({ state: true, msg: "Data Inserted Successfully..!" });
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
      res.json({ state: false, msg: "Data Inserting Unsuccessfull..!" });
    });
  res.send("Success");
});
```

**This is my model file:**

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.schema;

const classTimeTableSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  className: { type: String, require: true },

  monday: {
    1: { type: String, require: true },
    2: { type: String, require: true }
  },
  tuesday: {
    1: { type: String, require: true },
    3: { type: String, require: true }
  }
});

const classTimeTable = (module.exports = mongoose.model(
  "classTimeTable",
  classTimeTableSchema
));
```

Comment: What does your connect look like? Something like this works `mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/myapp', {useNewUrlParser: true});` - from [docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html)

Comment: There’s no such thing as a JSON object, and having weekdays as column names seems like wrong database design

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to add the option useNewUrlParser: true where you connect to your mongodb. It also clearly states it in the provided error. The notice that headers are already send is that you already used an output before so that is probably just cause you are not catching your errors correctly.

So find your connection to the DB probably somewhere in a config file or app setup/bootstrap and simply add that option **useNewUrlParser: true**